# Unmet Dependency while installing RStudio on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, r, gdebi, rstudio

So I downloaded RStudio and I tried installing it with Gdebi on my Ubuntu 16.10

```
sudo gdebi rstudio-0.99.903-amd64.deb
```

The error message

```
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libgstreamer0.10-0
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` ,  `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get install -f` and post the output at [paste Ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: @M.Becerra http://paste.ubuntu.com/23968632/

Comment: Thats not the output of the three commands, but if you did updating, upgrading and fixing dependencies fix anything?